# Stack Exchanges sites overflow bug

Tags: bug, design, stackexchange.com

On the [sites menu grid view](https://stackexchange.com/sites?view=grid), if you click on the far-right icons the popup boxes pop up, but appear off the edge of the browser window width.

For example:

[image: SE sites bug]

This happens both on Chrome 55 and IE 11 (ugh)

<sub>(note - please ignore the padlocks - it's my school's whitelist policy)</sub>

Comment: What screen resolution you have?

Comment: @Adam what is the official minimum supported screen resolution? Don't remember seeing it mentioned anywhere. (e.g. [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56161/which-browsers-are-officially-supported-and-what-else-do-i-need))

Comment: @ShadowWizard on Q&A, the content width is ~1100px, so whatever's slightly larger than that for the horizontal resolution. But, I mean, anything is technically supported - just depends on how much horizontal scrolling you want to tolerate.

Comment: @Adam of course, meant to ask about display without having horizontal scroll bar, as in this question. (Valid to have different minimum requirement for Q&A sites and stackexchange.com :-))

Comment: @ShadowWizard Browser window width: 1217, Browser window height: 655.  Surely it shouldn't push the size of the webpage out, it should just 'fit'.  Some faulty CSS, I presume...

Comment: Yeah, probably... though it does work fine on bigger screens, e.g. my own which is 1920 pixels in width.

Comment: I can replicate this. **Chrome 57.0.2987.133 (macOS)** with a screen resolution of **1366 x 768** and a browser size of **1366 x 584**.

Comment: Oh, I can repro it now @Cai. Ignore my previous comment. (I didn't try the popups that did make a horizontal scroll bar)